# ORMLite delete records that field is on another collection

Tags: java, android, ormlite

I want to delete a list of Seller objects from my database, which the Seller age corresponds to a integer that are in another collection, example:

This is my model:

```
class Seller {
  @DatabaseField(id = True)
  int id;
  @DatabaseField
  int age;
}
```

Now i have a `List<Seller> sellers` which have inside 3 Sellers with 3 different ages, `22, 25, 26`, i mapped this ages to another `List` to facility the queries, and now i have a `List<Integer> ages` which have inside the numbers `22, 25, 26`.

Now in my database a have a lot of sellers with different ages, i'm trying to delete the sellers which their ages matches one of in my `ages` list.

What i've done so far:

```
List<Integer> ages = Arrays.asList(22, 25, 26);
sellerDao.delete(sellerDao.deleteBuilder().where()
                .in(Seller.COLUMN_AGE, ages)
                .prepare());
```

But it gives me the following exception:
`` java.sql.SQLException: Unable to run delete stmt on object MappedStatement: DELETE FROM `seller` WHERE `age` IN (22, 25, 26 ) : DELETE FROM `seller` WHERE `id` = ? ``

What's the correct approach to run this deletion using ormlite?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DeleteBuilder` like this:

```
DeleteBuilder<Seller, Integer> deleteBuilder = sellerDao.deleteBuilder();
deleteBuilder.where()
             .in(Seller.COLUMN_AGE, ages);
deleteBuilder.delete();
```